# Splitting SQL Data Into Months

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a Datatable with several hundred rows for this year in it. (MS SqlServer 2k8)

I would like to split this data set out into customer enquiries / Month.

What I have so far is;

```
Select count(id) As Customers, DatePart(month, enquiryDate) as MonthTotal, productCode From customerEnquiries
where enquiryDate > '2012-01-01 00:00:00'
group by productCode, enquiryDate
```

But this then produces a row for each data item. (Whereas I want a row per month for each data item.)

So how do I change the above query, so that instead of getting

```
1 1 10
1 1 10
1 1 11
1 2 10
1 2 10
```

...

I get

```
2 1 10    <-- 2 enquiries for product code 10 in month 1
1 1 11    <-- 1 enquiries for product code 11 in month 1
2 2 10    <-- 2 enquiries for product code 10 in month 2
etc
```

And as a bonus question, is there an easy way of naming each month so the output is Jan, Feb, March instead of 1,2,3 in the month column?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
Select count(id) As Customers, DatePart(month, enquiryDate) as MonthTotal, productCode From customerEnquiries
where enquiryDate > '2012-01-01 00:00:00'
group by productCode, DatePart(month, enquiryDate)
```

This may help you.

Comment: Thanks, When I amend the query to get more data it goes back to the 1,1,1,1 format, but I'll try to see why thats breaking before I come back adn ask more questions!

Answer (score 2):

For the Bonus, `DATENAME(MONTH, enquiryDate)` will give you the name of the Month.

Comment: You may need to add `DatePart(year,....`  in your group if your dates are not all from same year, watch out!

Comment: This will always return `january`. If you want it to work, do `DATENAME(MONTH, enquiryDate)` .